# $\sum_{k \geq 1} e^{it \sqrt{\lambda_k}}$ - Theory of distribution

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, circles, distribution-theory, trace

An exercise asks to find the wave trace $w(t)=\operatorname{tr} \left(e^{it \sqrt\Delta}\right)=\sum_{k \geq 1} e^{it \sqrt{\lambda_k}}$   as a distribution (or generalized function) of the Laplacian on the $1$-D circle. (Hint : spectrum ($\mathbb{S}^1)=\{k^2 : k \in \mathbb{N}^*\}$)

I thought I should compute $\langle w,\varphi\rangle =\int_{\mathbb{S}^1} \left(\sum_{k \geq 1} e^{itk}\right) \varphi(t) \, dt$, where $\varphi \in D(\mathbb{S}^1)$, However, this is a wrong answer, but how do I have to interpret the Wave trace as a distribution in considering spect ($\mathbb{S}^1$)? Is there anyone could give me a track of reflexion? Do I have to consider the transformation $t \to |t|$ such that $t=(x,y) \in \mathbb{S}^1$?

So far I think we should obtain $$\langle w,\varphi\rangle =\int_{\mathbb{S}^1} \left(\sum_{k \geq 1} e^{i|t|k}\right) \varphi(t) \, dt =  \sum_{k \geq 1} \int_{\mathbb{S}^1} \left(e^{i|t|k} \varphi(t) \right) \, dt \stackrel{??}{=} \sum_{k \geq 1} e^{ik} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1  \varphi(r, \theta) r \, dr d\theta. $$

From this time, we could compute it with the Poisson Summation Formula.

From the bottom of the page $27$ of the [pdf](http://www.waltervansuijlekom.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/ThesisLuukVerhoeven.pdf), we could find an example on the real line instead of $\mathbb{S}^1$

Comment: (see my answer, I didn't get where the integral comes from)

Comment: When we discuss of distribution, this is related to the definition of page 2 of the book : https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/a-guide-to-distribution-theory-and-fourier-transforms.pdf. That's why I use the integral : $<w, \varphi> = \int_{\Omega} w \varphi$ for some test functions $\varphi$.

Comment: I have no problems with distributions, but you have to define a space of test functions first, here it is not obvious what is your space of test functions.... and my answer is more about what I understand of your question, than a definitive answer. the problem is that $t$ runs on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, not on $\mathbb{S}^1$, so I don't see how it is related to the space of test functions on the circle, and to distributions on the manifold/circle. do you see what I mean ?

Comment: search ' but rather as a distribution on' in your pdf http://www.waltervansuijlekom.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/ThesisLuukVerhoeven.pdf you'll see that talk of distributions on $\mathbb{R}$. so the answer is : $\langle w, \phi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} tr(e ^{i t \Delta^{1/2}}) \phi(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(t)}{e^{-it} - 1} dt$ for any test function $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: I edited again, final answer (have to integrate by part because $\int_{\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(t)}{e^{it} - 1} dt$ is defined only in principal value)

Comment: The exercise asks to find the trace of the Laplacian as a distribution on the 1-d (1-dimensional manifold) circle. That's why I thought I had to use $\Omega = \mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: (maybe there is a typo in your exercice ?) I don't think they consider distributions on $\mathbb{S}^1$, I'm 99% sure they are talking as in your pdf of distributions on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @user1952009 I'm pretty sure that there's a little problematic in your answer, because $tr(e^{i t \sqrt{\Delta} })$ should be convergent. In the problem $t>0$, then $|e^{itk}|>0$. According to some sources, the final answer should be expressed in using the $\delta$-function.

Comment: according to "some source" ? and I used that the distribution is defined as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|\infty}^\infty w(t+\epsilon) \phi(t) dt$, but maybe this step isn't the definition you are expecting

Comment: and if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{i t k} = \frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}$ , $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{itk} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-2 n \pi)$

Comment: Yes, only if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{i t k} = \frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}$, but it doesn't

Comment: it does in term of distributions : for any test function vanishing at each $2 k \pi, k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ : $\langle \frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}, \phi \rangle$ is well-defined, and is clearly equal to $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \langle \frac{e^{it-\epsilon}}{1-e^{it-\epsilon}}, \phi \rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \langle \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{(it-\epsilon)k}, \phi \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle e^{itk}, \phi \rangle$. now this distribution extends to any test function by integration by part : $\langle-i \ln(1-e^{it}),\phi' \rangle$. everything is rigorous

Comment: the obtained $\phi \mapsto \langle-i \ln(1-e^{it}),\phi' \rangle$ is clearly a continuous linear form on the space of test functions, and is equal to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  w(t) \phi(t) dt$ when this integral is well-defined, so to me it has to be the answer

Comment: @user1952009 Maybe just a last little detail : What do you mean by "in term of disbributions" for the convergence?

Comment: I added a note in my answer to explain it, and make everything rigorous

Comment: I'm not sure there was possible to do better; I understand everything clearly. Thanks!

Comment: thank you too the question was interesting, and at first I didn't know the answer. I should have talked before of the fact that the Fourier transform of Schwartz function (and hence test functions) is also a Schwartz function.

Comment: and could you tell me where does your question come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Laplacian is diagonalized in the orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions $(u_k)$ and $$\Delta \varphi = \sum_k u_k \langle u_k, \varphi \rangle \lambda_k$$ this [operator is normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator) hence $\Delta^a$ means : $$\Delta^a \varphi = \sum_k u_k \langle u_k, \varphi \rangle (\lambda_k)^a$$ and for any complex number $t$ : $$e^{i t \Delta^{1/2}} \varphi = \sum_{m=0}^\infty (it)^m \frac{\Delta^{m/2}}{m!} \varphi =  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(it)^m}{m!}  \sum_k u_k \langle u_k, \varphi \rangle (\lambda_k)^{m/2} =  \sum_k u_k\langle u_k, \varphi \rangle\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(it)^m}{m!}  (\lambda_k)^{m/2} = \sum_k u_k\langle u_k, \varphi \rangle e^{it (\lambda_k)^{1/2}}$$

from this the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class) of the operator is : $$tr(e^{i t \Delta^{1/2}})  = \sum_k e^{it (\lambda_k)^{1/2}}$$

given that in $\mathbb{S}^1$ the eigenvalues are $\lambda_k = k^2, k \ge 1$, if $Re(it) < 0$ (so that $|e^{it}| < 1$) you get : $$tr(e^{i t \Delta^{1/2}})  = \sum_{k =1}^\infty  e^{it k} = \frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}$$

and this is indeed the answer. in terms of distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ (see [page 26 of your pdf](http://www.waltervansuijlekom.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/ThesisLuukVerhoeven.pdf) ),

with $w(t) = tr(e^{i t \Delta^{1/2}})$ : $$\langle w, \phi \rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty w(t+i \epsilon) \phi(t) dt = -i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(t) \ln(1-e^{it})dt\qquad \qquad \phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})  $$

---

Note that with $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{itk}$ is not well-defined as a function, but it is as a distribution. By the properties of test functions $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, we know that the Fourier transform $\hat{\phi}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i \omega t} \phi(t) dt$ is a Schwartz function (see [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space#Properties)), hence $T(\phi)   =\sum_{k= 1}^\infty \langle e^{i t k},\phi \rangle = \sum_{k= 1}^\infty \hat{\phi}(k)$
is an absolutely convergent series. by integration by parts : $$T(\phi) = \sum_{k= 1}^\infty \frac{i}{k}\langle e^{i t k},\phi' \rangle = -i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ln(1-e^{it}) \phi'(t) dt$$
(where $\ln(1-e^{it})$ is locally integrable ($L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$) hence $\phi \mapsto -i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ln(1-e^{it}) \phi'(t)$ is automatically a well-defined distribution).

Hence, in the sense of distributions, with $\Delta$ the Laplacian on the circle : $$\langle tr(e^{it \Delta^{1/2}}), \phi \rangle = \sum_{k= 1}^\infty \langle e^{i t k},\phi \rangle  = -i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ln(1-e^{it}) \phi'(t) dt$$

Comment: Do you have information how to express $\langle-i \ln(1-e^{it}),\phi' \rangle$ in term of the Dirac-$\delta$-function?

Comment: @Sharpie : what do you mean ? (if $\phi$ is real) the real part will be something  like $\sum_{n-\infty}^\infty \phi(2 \pi n)$, but there is also the imag part

Comment: Consider $\phi$ be a real function. I want to know if it is possible to get something like $-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ln(1-e^{it}) \phi'(t) dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}} something* \delta (something)* \phi ' (t) dt$.

Comment: @Sharpie : the Fourier series inversion theorem / or the Poisson formula is that (in the sense of distributions) : $1+ 2\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \cos(2 \pi t k) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{2 i \pi k t} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-n)$, so $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{2 \pi itk}  = -1/2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-n) + i\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(2\pi nt)$$ and since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{2i  \pi t k} = \frac{1}{e^{-2i \pi t} -1}$, $$i\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(2\pi nt) = Im(\frac{1}{e^{-2i \pi t}-1}) =\ldots$$